# Streaming data from a wcf service with Java client

Tags: java, android, interop, ksoap2

I am developing an Android application which consumes some wcf services and visualises the data to the user. I connect with the service using KSOAP2 exchanging buffered messages.

The thing is that some services return large amount of data so the only way for this to be done is via streamedRespose, and then do a lazy load of the data to the user.

My question is how can I receive and use a stream with ksoap2 from a wcf web service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to consume Session dependent WCF services using Ksoap2-Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101059/how-to-consume-session-dependent-wcf-services-using-ksoap2-android)

Comment: kane mas thn xarh re 2 xronia meta